# Is programmatic access to Stack Exchange Data Explorer (SEDE) allowed?

Tags: support, data-explorer

The awesome functionality of the Data Explorer allows humans using a browser to run T-SQL and retrieve data.

Is programmatic access allowed? (To send some T-SQL via a Python script and return the results to the session.)

#### Notes

- I checked the see if the API accepts T-SQL (like the Data Explorer does), but I [cannot find any explicit mention of it](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs), although I would be grateful for any correction
- I can see the API provides a lot of general information ([e.g. around users, posts, answers, etc.](https://data.stackexchange.com/help)), but perhaps not nearly as nuanced as that which is achievable through T-SQL.

Comment: There is no api, SEDE is its own sub-system.  Get ahead by [downloading the data](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange).

Comment: Relevant / related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301214/choosing-best-resource-for-crawling-data-from-stack-exchange-sites/301217#301217

Comment: also related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250977/how-do-i-automate-the-data-explorer-download/250990#250990

Comment: There is an unsupported, not checked if still working, a for one specific query written [SEDE Client](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/SOCVR-Chatbot/tree/master/source/SOCVR.Chatbot/Sede) as part of SOCVR's chatbot. That has run and worked as long as we stayed under the IP ban limits imposed by SE.

Comment: It's "allowed" in the sense that you could probably make it work and, so long as you're not causing problems for anyone else, we're probably unlikely to even notice... But, I have to ask out of curiosity if nothing else: what are you trying to do that couldn't be done with the [actual API](https://api.stackexchange.com) and post-processing results in your Python code instead?

Comment: @AdamLear I was hacking around and was going to build either an R or Python library to connect to it. My current thinking is that it might be easier to simply take the BigQuery route, a little more setting up easy after that

Comment: @AdamLear the actual use case involves downloading data for around 1-2000 questions at a time (but it must scan all questions for a particular tag) and the questions are quite specifically chooses based on reasonably nuanced sql. I am aiming to have the available to python/R users in about 20 seconds (10 seconds query time, 10 seconds download), any longer could be too slow for users to enjoy